# Cannot see individual asset files in browser developer tools in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In my Rails 4 project, individual asset files are combined into one application.js/css file even in development. I can only see one big application.js/css file in my browser developer tools.

It seems to be one of the configurations in development.rb, but I am not sure which.

Comment: you need to add "config.assets.enabled = false" to your <environment>.rb file

Comment: Welcome to the asset pipeline. Give it a read here: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html.